# Finding nearest set of numbers given a position

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks something like so:

```
exons = {'NM_015665': [(0, 225), (356, 441), (563, 645), (793, 861)], etc...}
```

and another file that has a position like so:

```
isoform    pos    
NM_015665    449
```

What I want to do is print the range of numbers that the position in the file is the closest to and then print the number within that range of numbers that the value is closest to. For this case, I want to print `(356, 441)` and then `441`. I've successfully figured out a way to print the number in the set of numbers that the value is closest to, but my code below only takes into account 10 values on either side of the numbers listed. Is there any way to take into account that there are a different amount of numbers between each set of ranges?

This is the code I have so far:

```
with open('splicing_reinitialized.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        pos = row['pos']
        name = row['isoform']
        ppos1 = int(pos)
        if name in exons:
            y = exons[name]
            for i, (low,high) in enumerate(exons[name]):
                if low -5 <= ppos1 <= high + 5:
                    values = (low,high)
                    closest = min((low,high), key = lambda x:abs(x-ppos1))
```

Comment: How are you defining 'closest to'?  Are the pairs in the dictionary ranges?  Are they x,y coordinates?  How come in the dictionary you have pairs but the position is only one number?

Comment: @huck_cussler Ranges. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: As a sidenote. Take a look at `snpEff`. It feels like you're reinventing the wheel :) the tool produces complete annotation for any genomic position, including the information you want.

Comment: @Eli Thank you for the snpEff note. I'll definitely look into it. I'm trying to do some more complicated alterations to my data after this step, which made me think I had to do it by hand. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite it as a minimum distance search:

```
if name in exons:
    y = exons[name]
    minDist = 99999 # large number
    minIdx = None
    minNum = None
    for i, (low,high) in enumerate(y):
        dlow = abs(low - ppos1)
        dhigh = abs(high - ppos1)
        dist = min(dlow, dhigh)
        if dist < minDist:
            minDist = dist
            minIdx = i
            minNum = 0 if dlow < dhigh else 1
    print(y[minIdx])
    print(y[minIdx][minNum])
```

This ignores the search range, just search for the minimum distance pair.

Comment: Is there any way to print the `y[minIdx]` and `y[minIdx][minNum]` separately?

Comment: I can get the correct results when I print the way you have it set, but when I try to separate the two, it starts to print all of the ranges and then the value that's closest to the position in that range

Answer (score 1):

A functional alternative :). This might even run faster. It clearly is very RAM-friendly and can be easily parallelized due to the perks of functional programming. I hope you'll find it interesting enough to study.

```
from itertools import imap, izip, ifilter, repeat


def closest_point(position, interval):
    """:rtype: tuple[int, int]"""  # closest interval point, distance to it
    position_in_interval = interval[0] <= position <= interval[1]
    closest = min([(border, abs(position - border)) for border in interval], key=lambda x: x[1])
    return closest if not position_in_interval else (closest[0], 0)  # distance is 0 if position is inside an interval


def closest_interval(exons, pos):
    """:rtype: tuple[tuple[int, int], tuple[int, int]]"""
    return min(ifilter(lambda x: x[1][1], izip(exons, imap(closest_point, repeat(pos, len(exons)), exons))), 
               key=lambda x: x[1][1])


print(closest_interval(exons['NM_015665'], 449))
```

This prints

```
((356, 441), (441, 8))
```

The first tuple is a range. The first integer in the second tuple is the closest point in the interval, the second integer is the distance.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you for the suggestion :)